# Are different versions of movies being released on purpose? or do some cinemas censor parts of movies?

Tags: consumer-products, mind-control

I have seen movies at different cinemas, but sometimes I could swear that some scenes were addded or removed to the point of almost making the movie having a completely different impact! First time I noticed this was watching the "Brotherhood of the Wolf" ( french movie ) at the same cinema two days apart.  Seeing the second time with a friend there were additional scenes that depicted the torment of the "bad guy" to the point of feeling pity for him, yet at the first screening without those scenes he just aperaed to be an evil dude by choice!

That was my most notable recollecation of this issue, but for years been wondering if some cinemas on purpose been showing a different version than others, or even the cinema decides to split some scenes?

I know that TV stations cut movies to fit them within a time frame, but each cinema and potentially groups of people are segregated from others as hardly people watch the same movie twice at different locations.

So the question is, is it a common practice to have separte releases by suburb, even movie times where different groups of people walk away with differnt impressions of the movie?  ( it is possible different regional releases are edited for cultural issues but edits with the same city, suburb or cinema timing?)

Comment: The conspiracy tag doesn't really work, so I removed it.

Comment: @Monkey : Cool Tx,

Comment: The way the cinema system works(in India at least) is that the version of the film you show in the cinema has to be certified and rated by the censor board. So one cinema hall just can't go ahead and edit a movie, only the producers can do it with subsequent re-certification by the censor board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the United States, [The King's Speech](http://insidemovies.ew.com/2011/03/24/the-kings-speech-pg-13-version/) was censored by the distributor after the Oscars to remove f-words so as to obtain a different rating.

Other films have seen different editions, with descriptions such as "the Director's Cut".  [Brotherhood of the Wolf](http://www2.prnewswire.com/cgi-bin/stories.pl?ACCT=104&STORY=/www/story/08-15-2008/0004868161&EDATE=) is an example of this, at least for DVD, so perhaps the cinema discovered this and changed the edition it was showing.